# Deploying serverless, getting "user already exists" error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

Serverless Error:

> An error occurred: SDynamoDbTable - space-serverless-beta-dynamodb-test-user already exists.

I'm redeploying serverless once deployed in  another system, but I'm getting this error.

I'm getting while deploying `serverless.yml` using command:

```
sls deploy -s test
```

Answer (score -1):

Your deployment is trying to create a new DynamoDB table, but theres already a table with that name (`space-serverless-beta-dynamodb-test-user`.)

Either do not include a table name in your configuration or ensure the table name you have configured does not conflict with existing tables.

If you want to deploy this project to the same AWS account but for different stages, you can add the stage to the table name (ie. `space-serverless-beta-dynamodb-${opt:stage}-user`.)